# Convolutional Neural Networks regularization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, conv-neural-network, dropout

I'm working on CNN and I have a question about regularization. Max-norm constraints (a form of gradient clipping) apply a rescale of the weight vector that satisfies $|W|_2<c$, normally in the layer where Dropout is applied. If we apply a Lagrange multiplier to the function that satisfies this constraint we have $+λ (||W||_2-c)$ that is the same that apply L2 norm ($+λ ||W||_2$) to the layer where Dropout is applied, adding the term $-λ c$. That's why I think that apply max norm constraints and L2 norm are actually the same. Please, correct me if I wrong!

PS: Reference that says they are different.

G. Hinton, N. Srivastava, A. Krizhevsky, I. Sutskever, R. Salakhutdinov. 2012. Improving neural networks by preventing co-adaptation of feature detectors.

> We use the standard, stochastic gradient descent procedure for
>   training the dropout neural networks on
>   mini-batches of training cases, but we modify the penalty term that is
>   normally used to prevent the weights from growing too large. Instead
>   of penalizing the squared length (L2 norm) of the whole weight vector,
>   we set an upper bound on the L2 norm of the incoming weight vector for
>   each individual hidden unit. If a weight-update violates this
>   constraint, we renormalize the weights of the hidden unit by division.
>   Using a constraint rather than a penalty prevents weights from growing
>   very large no matter how large the proposed weight-update is. This
>   makes it possible to start with a very large learning rate which
>   decays during learning, thus allowing a far more thorough search of
>   the weight-space than methods that start with small weights and use a
>   small learning rate.

Comment: The reference you quote talks about *clipping* the weight vectors of *individual* hidden units versus *penalizing* based on the *whole* weight vector, which then apparently includes the weights of *all* hidden units. So the weight vector $W$ is not the same in both cases, as you seem to think from the way your question is formulated. Maybe you can try to edit your post and formulate your question concretely?

Comment: $W$ are the same, the weights where the Dropout is applied. As I say, imagine that L2 norm is only used in the last layer the same as the max-norm.